# Web Config and IIS

Tags: css, .net, security, iis, web-config

We are trying to provide fix for vulnerability issues from our website. We are facing Cross Site Scripting threat in our website(Vulnerability Testing Result). We put four lines of code in web.config. Now i need a clarification that how much time it will take to reflect the changes in IIS that were made in web.config and also is there any time criteria for this.

Comment: Modification on `web.config` triggers ASP.NET reload. So changes should take effect almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

It will do not take a longer time to affect the web.conifg changes in iis. it is instant. you just need to refresh the site in iis to reflect the changes you made in config file.

[image]